# Error calculation in this Fixed point iteration

Tags: numerical-methods

How many iterations to get accuracy within $10^{-8}$

$g(x)= 1/3\cdot\ln(2-x^2)$ when $x_0=0.5$
I used $|0.186539-0.5|\cdot{\lambda}^{n}/(1-\lambda) $ where $\lambda = 2/3$ and got $n \geq 46$

but I smell a mistake.

**Note:** the original question is $f(x)= e^{3x}+x^2-2$, does it converge to zero $\alpha \in (0,1)$ for any $x_0\in(0,1)$

Comment: What is "k" representing?

Comment: @Moo Oh, is k the actual value? I got n as 11.8 so round up to 12 and done?

Comment: Oh, k is what we use as $\lambda$.

Comment: So I got k or $\lambda$ to be 2/3 and my substitution gave me 43.7 so is it 44?

Comment: Just to clarify, the 'max' business is $\ln(0.5)$? And really? This is an estimate?